# Having more than 10 letter on header while exporting SHP to Excel using ModelBuilder ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder, excel, limitations

When I export a shapefile to Excel from ArcGIS using ModelBuilder  the header maximum length is 10. I would like to know how can I have more.

Comment: Migrate your spatial data from the old shapefile format into the file geodatabase format. That can have longer field names and also aliases. Don't know what they are? Read the help file

Comment: Your shapefile couldn't have field names longer than 10.  If your table shows field names longer than that in your project it would be because you used field aliases.  Unfortunately any aliases created in ArcMap for a shapefile or feature class can't be exported using the Table to Excel file, despite the option in that tool to use field aliases as column headings.  I think that only aliases created in ArcCatalog in feature classes are covered by that option and if you edit those in ArcMap those edits won't go.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible. This is because shapefiles cannot store [field names of more than 10 characters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00126-00150-000142.htm). (Shapefile is an old format from the 1990s)

If you convert a data table into shapefile format, the field names are truncated (if longer than the limit). So, if you had longer field names, the information is already lost when it's converted to a shapefile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know a way to actually export it? I’ve tried to convert it to gdb first but the problème it’s that instead of erasing the data each time I use my builder it create a new files in the gdb, and it’s not a solution

Comment: @Amine1992 What is your original data format? If it's shapefile, it couldn't have any field names that are longer than 10 characters. Exporting to gdb first wouldn't help since the source data has at most 10 characters for each field name. If your original data is in another format such as gdb., then try to skip the shapefile part, as it is the bottleneck.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will try to skip the shp part of it !